# only last line gets saved in text file in c++

Tags: c++, file-io

my code only saves the last line for eg if i enter 1 abc then press enter and then type 2 def then only 2 def is saved in txt file.
here is my code :-

```
int main()
{
 ofstream rankings;
 rankings.open("rankings.txt");
 cout << "Enter rank of the Student <space> followed by Name\n"
  "Press Ctrl+Z to quit"<< endl;
 int rank;
 string name;
 while (cin >> rank >> name);
 {
  rankings << rank << ' ' << name << endl;

 }
 rankings.close();


 return 0;
}
```

Comment: and don't quit with Ctrl+Z but with Ctrl+D

Comment: @GerardRozsavolgyi That's OS/Terminal dependent.

Comment: you'r right so just say under Linux and MacOS should be CTRL+ D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a superfluous semicolon after your `while` loop:

```
while (cin >> rank >> name);
                        // ^
```

This will just open a new block in the code afterwards, and leave you with the least values input.

To fix change your loop to

```
while (cin >> rank >> name) {
  rankings << rank << ' ' << name << endl;
}
```